# Docker build and push using JIB takes a really long time

Tags: docker, maven, gradle, jib

I am using **Jib plugin** in maven to build and push image to a Docker private registry. But it takes a really long time to build and push image for ***infinite time***. The base image is **500 MB** size.
How can I reduce build time?

Comment: Where is the time spent?  You may want to use a profiler to find this out.

Comment: Process stocks at 27.3% in processing base image.

Comment: What does the java profiler say is the bottleneck? Use visualvm or the one in netbeans. When you know that it is much easier to diagnose.